# res render does not render the index.jade

Tags: node.js, server-side-rendering

I build an authentication method in Node which use Azure AD. I use h here fore the "javascript quickstart" template which Microsoft offers. The Goal is that the user(s) start with the login screen. When they successful authenticate with Azure AD then they will redirect to the landing page.

All works accept loading the landing page(index.jade).The user is still on the same page after authentication.

Below code which is responsible to render the (or redirect) the landing page

```
exports.login = function(req, res){
    console.info('Check on User')
    var user = req.body.user
    if(user){
       console.info('user exist')  
       console.info(user)
       console.info('now render the index page jade') 
       //res.render('../views/index')
       res.redirect('../views/index')

    }
```

The location of the index file is "{projectlocation}/views/index.jade" The folder location where the redirect/render take place is "{projectlocation}/routes/login.js".

Below output of the code:

```
Check on User
user exist
{
  '@odata.context': 'https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#users/$entity',
  displayName: 'username',
  givenName: 'user',
  jobTitle: '',
  mail: 'user@user.com',
  mobilePhone: '',
  officeLocation: '',
  preferredLanguage: 'nl-NL',
  surname: 'user',
  userPrincipalName: 'user@user.nl',
  id: '666666-bbb-4444-5555-8tt874yy60oo'
}
now render the index page jade
POST /Aanmelden 200 239.783 ms - -
GET /views/index 404 0.829 ms - 31
```

I also try base on the comments to change the res.render to res.redirect
see the below code. Now i get some more output but still not the desire result.

Comment: Try using `res.redirect(path-to-index.jade)`.

Comment: Ok, but what is the difference between redirect and  and render?

Comment: res.render() will render the view with data passed to it, res.redirect() will redirect a user to another page (at which point the request starts over)

Comment: It still not works. I adjusted the text of the question.